# Django files location

Tags: python, django, django-views

My project structure is:

- main

  - settings.py and etc.
- app1

  - views.py and etc.
- app2

  - views.py and etc.
- manage.py

I have decorators that I use in views at app1 and app2. Where should I locate file decorators.py? Options in my opinion:

1. create decorators.py in app1 folder and import this to  at app1.views and app2.views
2. create decorators.py in app1 folder and import this to app1.views and create decorators.py in app2 folder and import this to app2.views.py (decorators.py will contains the same code, not so good)
3. create decorators.py in main folder and import this to at app1.views and app2.views
4. Your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any choice will work. Which one is the best depends on the project and the relation between *app1* and *app2*:

- If they **both are independent apps** then you might consider choosing **option 2** nevertheless.
- If you have **other dependencies between them**, say *app2* defines a `post_save` for a model in *app1* or something like that then I would suggest **option 1**.
- If they are more just logical compartments within your project and **not actual standalone applications** I would go for **option 3**.

---

To some extent this is also a matter of personal preferences.

Some further reading for the interested ones:

- [Django's Documentation about decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/decorators/)
- [Working with Django View Decorators](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/07/working-with-django-view-decorators.html) by [simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/)